# Visual Studio ASP .Net MVC Intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2008, intellisense

the vs 2008 intellisense doesn't work if i use it inside html attribute. example

```
<form method="post" action="<%= Url.Action %>"
```

while i'm typing Url.Action the code hint doesn't work, instead it gave me options of files that can be used for the "action" value.

Is it normal that the intellisense doesn't work inside html attribute? or am'i missing something to fix this bug.

Comment: Another reason to get ReSharper!

Answer (score 2):

I think it's just that way for now. I have the same 'issue' but got used to it.

Tip: If I need Intellisense, I just create a separate <% %> bracket somewhere else temporarily (where Intellisense will work), write the code I need, and then copy it to where I need it.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed Visual Studio 2010 Beta 1 and it doesn't work in this version either. I really hope they fix this before the final release.

Edit: I just installed Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the update, really disappointed to hear its not in 2010 either :(